# IIS Redirect HTTP to HTTPS Redirect Loop

Tags: ssl, redirect, iis, https, url-rewriting

I have a site setup to use SSL certs and serve the site via https. However, I cannot get URL Rewrite to work properly to redirect attempted connection attempts to follow certain rules that will, in the end, result to a specific url being used.

For security reasons at this time, I will just say the domain is: example.com

What I am trying to do is the following.

- All rewrites should rewrite the base request to https://www.example.com/

For example, lets say I have these before/afters:

- Before: http://example.com/
- After: https://www.example.com/
- Before: http://example.com/hello/
- After: https://www.example.com/hello/
- Before: http://sub.example.com/
- After: https://sub.example.com/

And so on. However, no matter what example I use I can find online to perform HTTP to HTTPS redirects, I am left with IIS just causing infinite loops redirecting and never properly working.

Bindings on the site in IIS are as follows:

- Type: http / Host Name: www.example.com / Port: 80 / IP Address: *
- Type: http / Host Name: example.com / Port: 80 / IP Address: *
- Type: https / Host Name: www.example.com / Port: 443 / IP Address: *

Comment: Can you please add a list of your rules from web.config.

Answer (score 1):

I use this one

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: This yields the same issue with redirection loops.

Comment: I copied this from a server in production now.  Are you sure you dont have some other rewrite rules?

Comment: Yes, the only rewrite rule I have is this one when testing and it didn't prevent the loop from happening. Further investigation into the problem showed Cloudflare was partly to blame and I did manage to get it working though.

Comment: Though its an old post, I might be facing the similar problem with Let's Encrypt. Could you please let me know how you fixed it?